# Mybatis and oracle Query result error

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

Use mybatis, but sql fail.
But sqldeveloper, it's work well....
What should I do?

This is log.

DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] - ==> Parameters: 2016-07-04(String), 2016-07-04(String)
[2016-07-05 08:57:49] [DEBUG]
『org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger:invoke(72)』 Elapsed Time [0:00:00.000]

```
select A.REG_NO as REG_NO,
       C.CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER as CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER,
       C.NAME as NAME,
       B.ORG_NM as ORG_NM,
       A.TEL_NO as TEL_NO,
       to_date(A.BIRTH_DT,'yyyymmdd') as BIRTH_DT,
       C.APP_VERSION as APP_VERSION,
       to_date(A.REG_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') as REG_DT,
       to_date(A.NOTI_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') as NOTI_DT,
       to_date(A.CNFRM_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') as CNFRM_DT,
       A.CNFRM_TM as CNFRM_TM,
       to_char(C.LAST_LOGIN_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss') as last_login_date
  from smtc_patmst a,smtc_orgmst b,smtc_customer c
  where  to_char(C.LAST_LOGIN_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') between  '2016-07-04' /**P*/ and  '2016-07-04' /**P*/
    and A.ORG_CD=B.ORG_CD
    and a.TEL_NO=CRYPTO_AES256.DEC_AES(c.PHONE_NUMBER)
    and A.CNFRM_DT != ' '
  order by C.LAST_LOGIN_DATE DESC
```

Query Result[]: -1row

This is my sql.

```
[select A.REG_NO as REG_NO,
        C.CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER as CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER,
        C.NAME as NAME,
        B.ORG_NM as ORG_NM,
        A.TEL_NO as TEL_NO,
        to_date(A.BIRTH_DT,'yyyymmdd') as BIRTH_DT,
        C.APP_VERSION as APP_VERSION,
        to_date(A.REG_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') as REG_DT,
        to_date(A.NOTI_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') as NOTI_DT,
        to_date(A.CNFRM_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd') as CNFRM_DT,
        A.CNFRM_TM as CNFRM_TM, 
        to_char(C.LAST_LOGIN_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd:hh:mm:ss') as last_login_date 
  from smtc_patmst a,smtc_orgmst b,smtc_customer c  
  where to_char(C.LAST_LOGIN_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') between #{startdate,jdbcType=VARCHAR} and #{enddate,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    and A.ORG_CD = B.ORG_CD
    and a.TEL_NO=CRYPTO_AES256.DEC_AES(c.PHONE_NUMBER)
    and A.CNFRM_DT != ' ' 
  order by C.LAST_LOGIN_DATE DESC]
```

and my servlet

```
[String startdate = request.getParameter("startdate");
 String enddate = request.getParameter("enddate");

 if(startdate==null){
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   startdate = sdf.format(new Date());
   enddate = sdf.format(new Date());
   }

 session.insert("McDownload.getMcDownloadList","2016-07-04");
 session.insert("McDownload.getMcDownloadList","2016-07-04");

 List<McDownload> mcdownload = session.selectList("McDownload.getMcDownloadList");

 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

 String arrayListToJson = gson.toJson(mcdownload);

 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 out.print(arrayListToJson);
 out.flush();]
```

Comment: What is the SQL error you are getting? I can see Query Result[]: -1row

Comment: I don't see the SQL error , but just debug..

Comment: If i don't handle the exception(parameter = null) than error is

Comment: [2016-07-05 21:49:26] [ERROR]『oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError:throwSqlException(134)』
java.sql.SQLException

Comment: I solved my problem.

Comment: It cause by session.insert()<=

Comment: i should use session.select than session.insert